# What is the "_ZN7android16CameraParameters9isPreviewE" symbol?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying to port cyanogenmod 12.1 (based on 5.x android) on my LG D290n L Fino , which is a qualcomm msm8610 based device running Android KitKat. When I try to make use of the stock camera HAL module (packed with all the proprietary stock qcamera libs and the stock qcamera-daemon), I get an error about missing symbol "_ZN7android16CameraParameters9isPreviewE" during the dlopen of the camera HAL module (it is referenced by the "camera.msm8610.so" library) . The camera initialization then fails. I have done some research and I have found out that this symbol is located in libcamera_client.so (library is provided by frameworks/av package) on the stock kitkat rom. This symbol is offcourse missing from the lollipop library.

Does anyone know what is the code that defines this symbol?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's `android::CameraParameters::isPreview()`. If it were part of AOSP I would expect it to be defined in [KitKat's CameraParameters.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/kitkat-mr2-release/include/camera/CameraParameters.h),  but it's not there, suggesting that it was introduced by an OEM (or perhaps Cyanogen, though I don't see it [there either](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_av/blob/cm-13.0/include/camera/CameraParameters.h)).

If that's the case, your HAL module will only work with a customized `libcamera_client.so`.  It's possible the method in question is simple enough that you can reverse-engineer it and provide a replacement, but it does raise the question of whether other bits and pieces have been customized in subtler ways.